# using limit in get function - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.

Now,I would like to use `limit/offset` statement.

**My query** :

```
$data['all'] = $this->m_general->get('pm', array(
    'user_sender' => 1,
    'admin_delete' => 0
) , false);
```

For example :

I want using `limit 0,100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below.

Replace your values with ***limit*** and ***offset***

```
$data['all'] = $this->m_general->get('pm', array(
    'user_sender' => 1,
    'admin_delete' => 0
) , limit,offset);
```